# How to parametrise the Data flow source 1 and source 2 in the same SQL DB but two different tables

Tags: azure-data-factory, oracle-adf, fuzzy-logic

I am building a Data flow pipeline which will call control flow pipeline.

The solution I am trying to achieve is to implement the Fuzzy logic for two master table to find relevant matching.
As show on below screen capture, I am building the Data flow to connect to the underline tables in the same database, but connection is the same. I want to parameterise the table names hence I can use the same generic connection rather than creating new one for each table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryWB7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvY4R.png)

my issues are:

1. How can I send the table names from control flow to data flow via parameter
2. How can I brown the table's column names on the join condition as shown on the screen capture

I tried creating parameters on the control flow and it is appeared to be working, however I can't brows the table to pick the join columns from table 1 (source 1 ) table 2 ( source 2 )

Please see below where it is using BLOB storage, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXVQp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dataset parameters for this scenario.

Go to your dataset and create a string type parameter like below.

[image]

In the dataset, click on edit and use the parameter for the table name like this `@dataset().table_name`.

[image]

Make sure the **Schema** in the above dataset is empty. Now, give the dataset for the two sources in the dataflow.

For **join**, **the incoming schema should not be empty**. That means you should import the schema in the sources.

For that, go to **Dataflow debug** -> **parameters** -> give your table names in the parameters.

[image]

Now, go to the sources of the dataflow and import the mapping like below.

[image]

Similarly, do the same for the second source as well.

Give the columns in the join like below and set the fuzzy logic as per your requirement.

[image]

You can see the result in the preview of the join transformation. Give your sink dataset. All this process is for the debug of the join transformation.

To run the dataflow from pipeline, you need to give your table names for the parameters in the dataflow activity in the pipeline like below.

[image]

Run the pipeline and dataflow will succeed like mine.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs, I am getting below error: Error code
DF-SQLDW-InvalidBlobStagingConfiguration
Troubleshooting guide
Activity ID
a444d4de-4127-4ee0-bae7-551a85aa32db
Details
at Source 'source2': Blob storage staging properties should be specified, where could I find the BLOB storage properties ?

Comment: why are you using Blob storage? You mentioned that your source is from SQL database. Are you using any blob storage as staging?

Comment: yes, I am using SQL db as source for source 2 and source 3. Not sure where these errors are generating?

Comment: Check if you are using any blob linked service as staging in the source errors of the dataflow. Also check the staging in the dataflow activity settings.

Comment: Sorry, the exact step I am trying is Import projection, that is where I am getting this error

Comment: yes, I am using blob linked services. do I need to take that off?

Comment: You need to use your SQL dataset as sources and when you import the schemas, you need to follow the above procedure. Where exactly are you using Blob linked services here?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of where it is using staging link services. But I tested the connection and it is all good.

Comment: First check whether it is working fine or not without the staging.

Comment: you are the Champian! yes it worked w/o link staging path. well done.

Comment: I tried to debug the pipeline, and now it is asking staging link, once I assigned it, the below error thrown.  Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source2': Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.

Comment: @NaveenSharma, please response to above question, finger cross it will be last issue. thanks

Comment: @gamageg manjula, I think your source or sink is a SQL Datawarehouse i.e., Synapse Dedicated pool. Thats why you are receiving this error about the staging and master key. Follow this similar [ask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1350359/synapse-dataflow-when-enable-sqldw-staging-pipelin).

Comment: @Rakesh Govindula, I can't see the accept button to accept the solution.